# How to add custom skill adapter while converting an existing v4 bot to a skill

Tags: c#, botframework

I was following the steps mentioned in the below link to convert an existing v4 bot to a skill

https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/howto/skills/skillenablingav4bot/

I'm confused at Step 3, which says about creating a custom skill adapter.

How to do this ?

Should I create a new folder for Adapters ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here - the sample code looks simple enough. You can add it any folder you want?

Comment: Is there any specific code to be added with that sample code ? in the ... space left before SkillMiddleware.

Comment: Does the [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/templates/Skill-Template/csharp/Sample/SkillSample/Adapters) help?

Comment: Thanks.These examples are helpful. I have two errors one is at base(credentialProvider) it says "object does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument. And OnTurnError method is required or is it optional ?

Comment: Error handling is always 'optional', but generally a good thing. Don't know about the other one sorry, I haven't used BF in anger since v2.